# Can we hide system default fields from workItem form?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Can we be able to hide the system defaults fields on the workitem form?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For **TFS 2017, On-premises XML process model**: You can modify select elements within the SystemControls section, such as changing the EmptyText attribute value for the System.Title field. In general, we recommend you don't customize this section much more than that. For example, you can't remove fields from or add other fields within this section.

For **TFS 2018, On-premises XML and Azure DevOps Services, Hosted XML process models**: You can specify the ShowEmptyReadOnlyFields attribute, or select to hide or replace select fields defined within the SystemControls section.

For example, to hide the Reason field, you modify the Control element with the `Visible` attribute.

```
<Control Label="Reason" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="System.Reason" Visible="false" />
```

To replace the Reason field with another field, use the `Replaces` attribute. Also, remove the entry for the Reason field from within the section.

```
<Control Label="Milestone" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Fabrikam.Milestone" Replaces="System.Reason" />
```

See more info in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/weblayout-xml-elements?view=azure-devops#header-customization).

Answer (score 0):

If the process you are using is a custom process inherited from the template process, normally you can't hidden the default fields.

If your process is defined using a XML process model, as `@ShaykiAbramczyk` suggested, you can try to edit the XML file for the process definition to hidden the fields.